# How to prevent remote connections from another machine?

Tags: windows-7

Is it possible to prevent a connection to my Windows 7 computer in an Active Directory environment in any particular way.

There's a feature or option called **Connent to another computer** but I was't sure if I should or could use that in this case to accomplish blocking these remote connections. I also wasn't sure about stopping any particular services to prevent the remote connections.

I am a local administrator on this PC and have admin access to it.

Comment: Confirm whether your computer is part of AD or workgroup ?

Comment: Unless you have admin rights on your Computer and the Computer is part of the AD there's no way you can do that. What you could do is enable the Windows firewall and block all incoming ports.

Comment: @SeanClt, my computer is part of a workgroup.

Comment: @Spokey, I have admin rights. Could you give a tip on which ports should be locked first?

Comment: Did you ever get a chance to try my suggestions from my answer? .

Answer (score 3):

### This will not prevent local logins at the physical console - Remote Only

Since you say **you are a local administrator**, you could just block at the OS FW level with **NETSH** commands stopping the IP address(es) or the TCP ports for the traffic that needs blocked.

*Just be sure the **Windows Firewall is enabled** and then run the below from an **elevated command prompt**.*

**Get IP address of machine name**

```
PING <PCName>
```

---

### Blocking IP Addresses and TCP Ports Command Line NETSH

**Block everything from a specific IP address**

*(Plug in the IP address where the `<IPaddress>` is below)*

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="IP Block" dir=in interface=any action=block remoteip=<IPaddress>/32
```

**Block ALL standard RDP, SMB, WMI, SSH TCP ports**

*(add other TCP ports and commands below as needed for other protocols or ports to block)*

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="RDP Block" dir=in localport=3389 protocol=TCP action=block
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="WMIC RPC Block" dir=in localport=135 protocol=TCP action=block
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="SMB Block" dir=in localport=445 protocol=TCP action=block
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="SSH Block" dir=in localport=22 protocol=TCP action=block
```

**Undo or delete all the above rules**

*(used to undo or delete the above commands)*

```
netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name="IP Block"
netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name="RDP Block"
netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name="WMIC RPC Block"
netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name="SMB Block"
netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name="SSH Block"
```

---

### **Resources**

- [**List of TCP and UDP Port Numbers**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)
- [**Netsh AdvFirewall Firewall Commands**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd734783(v=ws.10).aspx)
- [**NETSH**](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html)

Answer (score 0):

***If your computer was part of Active Directory***

your AD Admins can connect to your computer

**As your computer is not part of Active Directory**

They would require your user/password to be able to do that, So as long as they don't know your user/password or local Administrator password they will not be able to connect to your machine remotely

your computer is not even part of Active Directory. So AD Admins can't just connect to your computer

Some service look into to disable Remote Administration

1. Remote Registry
2. Windows Management Instrumentation